# Unable to migrate Varbinary datatype using Nifi - PutDatabaseRecord Processor

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi

Using PutDatabaseRecord processor i trying to migrate the varbinary datatype to another destination. Inside i tried avro reader using "Use Embedded Avro schema". While migrating, processor showing error as  "THE CONVERSION FROM UNKNOWN TO ARRAY IS UNSUPPORTED".

Please provide solution for above issue. Thanks in advance

Error log:

17:04:34 ISTERROR5e288c7d-24fc-3619-7c08-e964a2113c7c
PutDatabaseRecord[id=5e288c7d-24fc-3619-7c08-e964a2113c7c] Failed to process session due to Failed to process StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=bd2a3c28-d19b-466d-a8cd-1a397a1ebb6d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1608723136100-388, container=default, section=388], offset=6847, length=45776044],offset=0,name=a241d7c9-7098-4161-bb77-bf205ef5bc2c,size=45775924] due to com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to ARRAY is unsupported.: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to process StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=bd2a3c28-d19b-466d-a8cd-1a397a1ebb6d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1608723136100-388, container=default, section=388], offset=6847, length=45776044],offset=0,name=a241d7c9-7098-4161-bb77-bf205ef5bc2c,size=45775924] due to com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to ARRAY is unsupported.

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6zCU.png)

Comment: Please provide solution for above issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Image is very low quality, can you provide info as a plain text?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] - and edit your question to contain textual content as text, not as image. Consider providing a [mcve]